# Make an auto anchor contents from h2 & h3 headers

Tags: jquery, header, anchor

I have found the following jQuery plugin, which does exactly what I'm after.

http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php

However I can't seem to figure out how to not only include the `h2` headers, but the `h3` headers also. I want the `h3` headers to be under the relative `h2` header and nested in slightly, as if it was a ul li ul li.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried??

Comment: It's in the link in my question. Direct link: http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/js/jquery.autoanchors-0.3.js

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry guys. Found a better one that does what I want. http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/toc/